# Substitute 4 digit numbers by their first digit

Tags: regex, r

I have a factor column filled with 4 digit numbers. I want to substitute the numbers by their first digit. For example:

The number 7819, I want to substitute by 7. 
The number 2538, I want to substitute by 2. 
The number 5181, I want to substitute by 5 and so on...
I have the following code:

```
df$colname<- sub("([0-9]+^7)","7",df$colname)
```

I want to do the substitution on the rows of the entire column.

Please, help me !!!

Thanks,

Comment: A `factor` is *not* a number. Do you mean that the factors are 4-character strings consisting of numerals?  And as the comments point out, are there any other characters or  negative signs?

Answer (score 5):

What about simply doing this:

```
 > substr("7819-",1,1)
 [1] "7"
```

Comment: I would note that this solution is miles (parsecs :-) ) faster than the others submitted.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: But, it is not general.  If the number is `negative`  For example substr("-7819",1,1)
[1] "-"

Comment: @akrun true but in the absence of any details from the OP, I'll claim that there aren't any negative numbers (or characters other than digits). Else we might need to return "-3" from "-3452" :-(

Answer (score 1):

Using capturing group:

```
> sub('(\\d)\\d+', '\\1', '2538')
[1] "2"
> sub('(\\d)\\d+', '\\1', '7819')
[1] "7"
> sub('(\\d)\\d+', '\\1', 'number 7819')
[1] "number 7"
> sub('(\\d)\\d+', '\\1', 'no number')
[1] "no number"
```

Comment: It will be difficult to use this code if I have to substitute the values for more than 12,000 rows

Comment: @user2913919, I used string literals to make it easy to demonstrate. Instead of the string literals, use vector if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
library(stringr)
vec1 <- c('2538', '7819', 'number 7819', 'no number')

str_replace(vec1,perl('(?<=[0-9])\\d+'), "")
#[1] "2"         "7"         "number 7"  "no number"
```

#### Explanation

`(?<=[0-9])\\d+`  Look behind for pattern matching any digit followed by numbers

Replace the numbers with `''`

#### Update

Not sure if `-` are also part of the string and if you want to replace it

```
vec2<- c('2538', '7819', 'number 7819', 'no number', '2583- fun', '-7256 something')
 str_replace(vec2,perl('(?<=[0-9])\\d+([[:punct:]]+)?'), "")
 # [1] "2"            "7"            "number 7"     "no number"    "2 fun"       
 # [6] "-7 something"
```

Comment: The - doesn't make part of the string.

Comment: I should have rewritten my problem much better.

Comment: I have a column whose rows contains numbers. Each number I want to substitute or replace by the number first digit.

Comment: For example: 5379 I want to replace by just 5

Comment: @user2913919, Thanks for the clarification.  If the column contains only numbers, then `substr` should work fine.  Hopefully, it is a numeric column.  Suppose if it is character column and you have " 5463", then substr(" 5463",1,1)
[1] " ".